# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smart_open.compression'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gensim

when i try to import gensim, i see this error message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smart_open.compression'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it using

```
!pip install smart_open
```

Write it in any code cell in your notebook.

Comment: And further, after such a shell-escape installation, you may need to restart the notebook's interpreter for it to find the new package.